# my app cannot receive wm_timer msg

Tags: windows, winapi

After created the window, i started a timer to do sth. the code like this:

```
SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 40, NULL);  //tick each 40 ms.
```

I traced the last error, which was 0. but i cannot receive wm_timer! code like this:

```
case WM_TIMER:
{
     //...
}
```

My IDE is VS2010, and OS is Windows7, so is there some speical case about my used environment?

P.S. okay i provide more code, it's a win32 app so in WinMain:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(...);  //style : WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE , return is good
SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 40, NULL);    //return is good too.
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

and the WndProc:

```
switch(message)
{
case WM_TIMER:
{
    DebugBreak();  //no reaction
}
break;
.......
}
```

Comment: yes, it is 1. good return.

Comment: You need to post more code. How you set up your WndProc and where you start the timer.

Comment: Also, is there a message loop running in the thread that creates the window and timer?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. In order to understand whether it is before even generating timer messages, or generating them but failing to handle properly, use `Spy++` SDK tool to check your window messages and finding out if timer messages are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_TIMER` won't fire if you're failing to consume other messages, as they will take priority. One cause of that, for example, is not correctly processing `WM_PAINT` messages (you must `BeginPaint()` / `EndPaint()` )

Comment: U got it! WM_PAINT msg is always sending so i cannot recv the WM_TIMER, haha.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my recollection, the problem stems from the fact you placed the SetTimer call too early. Place it in WM_CREATE.

```
switch(message)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 40, NULL);
    }
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        DebugBreak();  //no reaction
    }
    break;
    .......
}
```

I don't see any other reason why this should malfunction.

Comment: @KnowNothing in that case you should post some more code, like the whole main procedure. Something must be borked, this isn't nuclear physics :P

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If I put "`SetTimer()`" in the `WM_CREATE` section it does not start. However, if I create a menu option that I need to click on, and the put the "`SetTimer()`" function in there,
it works.

```
  case WM_CREATE:
    {
        SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, NULL); // does not work here
        return 0:
    }
    case ID_TIMER_START:
    {
       SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, NULL); // works here
       return 0;
    }
```